# pythonでforループ中に自動でリストの名前を変えたい

Tags: python

forループの中で数字に対応した名前のリストを生成したいです。
例えば

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(20):
        list_i_j=[i,j]
```

`list_i_j` に対応する数字が入るようなものです。それに代わる代替案でも大丈夫です。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

文字列処理で変数名を組み立てる事が必要な場面は、あまり無いと思います。
配列や連想配列が使えないshスクリプトなどでは使うかもしれませんが。

質問の例ですと `i` も `j` も連続しているのでリストのリスト（のリスト）を使いたいです。

```
a_list = []
for i in range(10):
    child_list = []
    a_list.append(child_list)
    for j in range(20):
        child_list.append([i, j])

# 内包表記バージョン
a_list = [[[i, j] for j in range(20)] for i in range(10)]

# >>> a_list[1][2]
# [1, 2]
```

リストが適さず、`"1_2"` の様な文字列から値を引きたい事情があるのでしたら、辞書を使うのがよさそうです。

```
a_dic = {}
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(20):
        a_dic[str(i) + "_" + str(j)] = [i,j]

# 内包表記バージョン
a_dic = {str(i) + "_" + str(j) : [i, j] for i in range(10) for j in range(20)}

# >>> a_dic["1_2"]
# [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

こういう事でしょうか？

```
for i in range(10):
  for j in range(20):
    exec("list_" + str(i) + "_" + str(j) + "= [i, j]")

# Check the existence of variables
# print globals()
```